# PHP mysql connection error : You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

I got this above error while running super easy code that any idiot can build it, so I don't know what and where or is my machine needs to be turned on and off or my luck is not working. Please help me or I'll start crying.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","some password","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, username,password,email)
                        VALUES('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]')");
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
header("Location:reg.php?remarks=success");
echo " record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You are running the query twice...

Comment: Why 2 times `mysqli_query()`?

Comment: Isnt it once? I learned from here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: `$sql` should be the query.

Comment: Just put `$sql="INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, username,password,email)
                        VALUES('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]')";`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/ (*as will these*) "life".

Comment: At least escape those values

Comment: @ProgrammingQueen Dont use this horrible horrible horrible page ... please. Do yourself that favor.

Comment: Its just I am in hurry, want to get done by morning

Comment: One more quick question, if anyone can help it would be great, I am getting query failed error for this query, I think this look good, Is there anything else wrong?                              $qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
 $result=mysqli_query($qry);

Answer (score 1):

Try wthout the database in con and select db separately.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","some password");
mysqli_select_db("dbname here",$con);
```

Answer (score -1):

This $_POST value are wrong.
Try with:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, username,password,email)VALUES('{$_POST['fname']}', '{$_POST['lname']}'...
```

Comment: $_POST is array, to call him need quotes '', this cleary is one of errors that they have in his code